# App not available for a specific phone | How to exclude TV in manifest

Tags: android

I'm trying to exclude TVs, but my app is shown as not supported in the Google Play store for Vodafone Smart 4 turbo phone - here are its specs

http://www.gsmarena.com/vodafone_smart_4_turbo-6507.php

Here is my Manifest:

```
 <uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<supports-screens
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<meta-data
android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
android:value="@string/app_id" />
<permission
android:name="com.arshad.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<compatible-screens>
<!-- all small size screens -->
<screen
android:screenDensity="ldpi"
android:screenSize="small" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="mdpi"
android:screenSize="small" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="hdpi"
android:screenSize="small" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
android:screenSize="small" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="480"
android:screenSize="small" />
<!-- all normal size screens -->
<screen
android:screenDensity="ldpi"
android:screenSize="normal" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="mdpi"
android:screenSize="normal" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="hdpi"
android:screenSize="normal" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
android:screenSize="normal" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="480"
android:screenSize="normal" />
<!-- all big screens -->
<screen
android:screenDensity="ldpi"
android:screenSize="large" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="mdpi"
android:screenSize="large" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="hdpi"
android:screenSize="large" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
android:screenSize="large" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="480"
android:screenSize="large" />
<!-- All extra big screens -->
<screen
android:screenDensity="ldpi"
android:screenSize="xlarge" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="mdpi"
android:screenSize="xlarge" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="hdpi"
android:screenSize="xlarge" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
android:screenSize="xlarge" />
<screen
android:screenDensity="480"
android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.arshad.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.location"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera"
android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="false" />
```

Comment: You know, if you want to open up to all screen sizes, don't put any `supports-screens` or `compatible-screens` tags in manifest.

Comment: Wouldnt that make it available for TVs as well? So you think its a screen type issue?

Comment: What kind of TV are you talking about and where did you read that you can filter them out like this?

Comment: I can't see any problem with them, but is easy thing to do to rule out. Also from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) `Caution: Normally, you should not use this manifest element.`

Comment: Is there a way that I can test whether the number of supported devices will increase if I change this, without having to upload an APK to google play?

Comment: I doubt it as the only accurate source would be google play. See here for how google play uses manifests for filters http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

Comment: thank you, I will try removing that tag

Comment: If for some reason it's not convenient to upload, make a new app to upload just for testing manifests (and not publish of course).

Comment: Well, google says 292 more devices are now supported but a list is not available, so I will find out whether that helped the next time we release, which is about to be soon

Comment: In play dev console, under APK, you can see "Supported devices" it has a number and a link "See list". That should show the list of devices.

Comment: Yeah, but that is applicable only to released versions. I just uploaded an APK without releasing it, and the number shown there is not clickable.

Comment: Are you trying to include or exclude TVs?

Comment: Your manifest appears to be attempting to include them, but in your comments you are worried about including them.

Comment: I want to exclude tvs

Comment: Look here: https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html You appear to have used the manifest definitions for **including** them, such as not requiring touch screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use these screen tags `supports-screens` and `compatible-screens`. Particularly as you are including everything, so there's really no need.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

> **Caution:** Normally, you should not use this manifest element. Using this element can dramatically reduce the potential user base for your application, by not allowing users to install your application if they have a device with a screen configuration that you have not listed. You should use it only as a last resort, when the application absolutely does not work with specific screen configurations.

## Exclude TVs

It turns out you are trying to exclude TVs. No need, it is opt-in and to **include** TVs you need to follow the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html#handle-features).

One of those instructions tells you to not-require these features like this:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.gps"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor"
        android:required="false"/>
```

This is something you **are** doing on the whole, so do not do that either if you do not want to be available TVs.

## Leanback requirement

TV support is definitely opt-in, as you need a specific `Activity` for TV launching from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html):

> **Caution:** If you do not include the `CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER` intent filter in your app, it is not visible to users running the Google Play store on TV devices. Also, if your app does not have this filter when you load it onto a TV device using developer tools, the app does not appear in the TV user interface.

I.e. your app will not be available in play if you do not have an activity with this intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Note also:

> Declaring a hardware feature as required by setting its value to true prevents your app from being installed on TV devices or appearing in the Android TV home screen launcher.

So for example, something like this would guarantee it will not work on TV.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="true"/>
```